# Checking case in where condition oracle

Tags: oracle, case, where-clause, clause

This is the query i have used to check condition. So far i didn't get the solution. When am execute got error as Missing keyword. How to do this.

```
 select * from customer where status='A' and (case when trim(member_since) is not null then member_since > TO_DATE ( '20160112 235959' , 'YYYYMMDD HH24MISS')
 else registration_date <=TO_DATE ( '20160112 235959' , 'YYYYMMDD HH24MISS') end)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite with a bit of boolean logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
WHERE     status = 'A'
   AND ( TRIM(member_since) IS NOT NULL AND member_since > TO_DATE('20160112 235959', 'YYYYMMDD HH24MISS') OR
         TRIM(member_since) IS NULL AND registration_date <= TO_DATE('20160112 235959', 'YYYYMMDD HH24MISS')
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from customer
where status='A'
  and trim(member_since) is not null and  member_since > TO_DATE ('20160112 235959', 'YYYYMMDD HH24MISS') 

  union all

  select *
from customer
where status='A'
  and trim(member_since) is  null and    registration_date <=TO_DATE ('20160112 235959', 'YYYYMMDD HH24MISS')
```